# Issue using free

Tags: c, pointers, free

I'm having a problem here with this code:

```
int main(int argc, **argv)
{
  ...
  char *dirlog
  ...
  dirlog = malloc(sizeof(getenv("LOG")+strlen("/logfile.log")));
  dirlog = strcat(getenv("LOG"),"/logfile.log");
  o = strlen(dirlog);
  ...
  free(dirlog);
}
```

The code compiles but when run, the program returns segmentation fault. I've tried to debug using the coredump file but the backtrace show only this:

```
#0  0x00007fb7f7e7e3ac in free () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000000000507739 in main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at testprogram.c:460
```

Any clue?

Comment: `sizeof` is *not* the correct thing to use here. Nor is invoking `strcat` as shown.

Comment: cannot concatenate into the output of `getenv` !!!

Comment: You're assigning another value to your already allocated variable. Have you tried using `strcpy` instead to put the content of `strcat` in the allocated `dirlog`?

Comment: Besides: (even after fixing the sizeof problem) `getenv()` can return NULL.

Comment: Please explain what each of your lines is supposed to do. Use comments to do so. You can extend this into following this very helpful article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to compute both string lengths using `strlen`, not `sizeof` (which only works for literals but avoid it anyway), but beware: `LOG` env. variable could be missing, so test against `NULL` before doing that.

My proposal uses `sprintf`, which avoids a lot of calls to `strcat` and `strcpy`, and allows to insert fixed-size literals like `/`

So a rather safe way of doing this would be:

```
const char *logroot = getenv("LOG");
if (logroot!=NULL)
{
    const char *logfile = "logfile.log";
    int len = strlen(logroot)+strlen(logfile)+2; // predict the size of the resulting string
    char *dirlog = malloc(len);
    sprintf(dirlog,"%s/%s",logroot,logfile);
    ...
    free(dirlog);
}
```

(I've added 1 for nul-terminator and 1 for the slash, that I'll include only when doing `sprintf`)

Answer (score 3):

Your `malloc` seems to be getting wrong arguments.

Manual page for `getenv` states,

> The getenv() function returns a pointer to the value in the environment, or NULL if there is no match.

And `strlen("/logfile.log")` would be a fixed number.

But, passing `sizeof` something which is addition of some char pointer and some number which is a length, that doesn't make sense.

`sizeof` is not what you need, thats what I can deduct.

We can reason the Segmentation Fault. The call to `malloc` must have failed and without validating it you proceed.

You don't check if `malloc` returned anything. Add that part,

```
char *ptr = getenv("LOG");

size_t sizeRequired = strlen(ptr) + 1 + strlen("logfile.log") + 1;
dirlog = malloc(sizeRequired);

if(dirlog == 0)
{
    // Handle the error here and return
}
```